# Trying to figure out a method of resizing background image and containing elements with ratio for width of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

So I have this navigation menu setup and despite the code for the CSS currently. The background-color is mostly for ascetics  at the moment. I need to have a background image on this setup. Its not really a fluid background either unfortunately due to the design spec set forth. So with that.

I need to make this background and the containing elements to make the navigation work the way I am hoping to resize according to the overall window size. From Desktop browser to mobile device.

Is there anyway anyone knows of achieving this with CSS alone or combined with something like jQuery? I have seen similar done on some platforms but have no idea how they tackled the solution

```
/* wrapper and master settings for over all containers */
#menu_bottom{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:999999;background-color:#F00;width:320px;height:172px;}
#menu_bottom > ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
#menu_bottom > ul > li{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;float:left;width:50px;height:172px;background-color:#000;}
/* inactive state (position) */
#menu_bottom > ul > li.fans{background-color:#0F0;}
#menu_bottom > ul > li.gameplan{background-color:#0F0;}
#menu_bottom > ul > li.dashboard{background-color:#0F0;}
#menu_bottom > ul > li.myteams{background-color:#0F0;}
#menu_bottom > ul > li.settings{background-color:#0F0;}

/* active state (position) */
#menu_bottom > ul > li.fans.active{background-color:#00F;}
#menu_bottom > ul > li.gameplan.active{background-color:#00F;}
#menu_bottom > ul > li.dashboard.active{background-color:#00F;}
#menu_bottom > ul > li.myteams.active{background-color:#00F;}
#menu_bottom > ul > li.settings.active{background-color:#00F;}

<div id="menu_bottom">
    <ul>
        <li rel="/" class="f<?php if($activeNav == "c"){echo ' active';} ?>"></li>
        <li rel="/" class="g<?php if($activeNav == "n"){echo ' active';} ?>"></li>
        <li rel="/" class="d<?php if($activeNav == "d"){echo ' active';} ?>"></li>
        <li rel="/" class="m<?php if($activeNav == "f"){echo ' active';} ?>"></li>
        <li rel="/" class="s<?php if($activeNav == "s"){echo ' active';} ?>"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an overall wrapper for all content and set it 100% width in CSS

Comment: That much I know. If it was as simple as a image that can fluidly repeat across the background I'd be all for that. Unfortunately its not. So the container can be 100%, but the clickable regions the `li` as well as the image itself have to change in size within an relative aspect ratio to match the containing elements size. As well as has to match on the event of the browser resizing.